# Embedding video player on RPi

Tags: video, vlc

I am developing an application which should have a GUI showing some text, pictures and playing video (the video should be on approximately 1/2 of the screen, the rest is text and static pictures).

This application should have been for Android at first, but now it changed to Linux on Raspberry Pi (or similar ARM board). So I reused some code from Android (in Java) and I got really stuck on following problem:

**Is there any video player with ARM HW acceleration, which can be embedded into (Java) application?**

I already tried Raspberry Pi and Banana Pi (with Allwinner A20 - there is VLC version which supports HW acceleration, but just in fullscreen mode) and I couldn't find any working solution. Currently I am willing to rewrite whole application in different programming language, if there is working video player binding for it.

Looking forward to any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

you can use omxplayer.

maybe you wanna take a look at a simple python omxplayer wrapper to get an idea for a wrapper: https://github.com/jbaiter/pyomxplayer/blob/master/pyomxplayer.py.

Good luck!

Paul

Comment: Thank you for your involvement Paul! Much appreciated. Do you have any example working with Java (as requested by OP)?